# BLDC Motor Driver with ATMEGA2560

Tags: avr, brushless-dc-motor

I have basic knowledge about AVR microcontrollers and AVR programming.In this days i am trying to design bldc motor driver.I want to use atmega2560 for controller of this driver.For this purpose i need 6 PWM output in 20kHz.I have found i can change the prescalers , top values and modes of timers then i can get 20kHz signal.But i have doubt aboout can i use 6 PWM output at the same time for commutation (mosfet drivers) ? Can i accomplish it with software ? What is your suggestions about that ? And as you know atmega2560 has 6 timers : 2x8 bit and 4x16 bit.Which pwm pins are  more suitable for me according to your experience ? I will appreciate for your help.Regards ; (I know there is a lot of AVR documentation and app notes about BLDC. I have researched and read a lot of them in a week but i couldn’t find my answer.I am very confused)

[image: General structure of circiut that i am trying to build]

Comment: There's cheaper microcontrollers specifically suited better for motor control applications. Why did you choose the slightly dated atmega2560? Its timers are small and it lacks a few classical tricks to make MOSFET bridge control easier/safer...

Comment: Motor drivers have built in deadtime and level shifters so you only need 3 signals.

Comment: You could have a look at betaflight which is a drone OS running on chip like the atmega, it is opensource and you could check the code as it does control up to 8 BDLC motors.

Comment: @Damien that's something different – that's controlling BLDCs that have controllers built in. Yunus wants to build that controller that's typically integrated in the motor.

Comment: @MarcusMüller you are right, in that case it's the ESC controller -> https://oscarliang.com/esc-firmware-protocols/ BLHeli_S which also works on the atmega2560